# Передача данных другим элементам на JS

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Как передать занчение одного элемента всем другим?
Например, имеется элемент

```
<span id="info">Information</span>
```

Нужно передать значение внутри данного , т.е. в данном случае "Information" другому элементу, например ссылке, чтобы получилось:

```
<a href="link" class="info">Information</a>
```

Значения id span и class a могут быть любыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - создать функцию и использовать ее для всех элементов, которым нужно установить новое значение. Чистый JS:

```js
function shareInfo(id) {
  var val = document.getElementById(id).innerText,
      els = document.querySelectorAll('.' + id);

  [].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    el.innerText = val;
  });
} 

shareInfo('info');
shareInfo('foobar');
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="info">Information</span>
  <a href="link" class="info">Something 1</a>
  <a href="link" class="info">Something 2</a>
  <a href="link" class="info">Something 3</a>
</p>

<p>
  <span id="foobar">Foobar</span>
  <a href="link" class="foobar">Something 1</a>
  <a href="link" class="foobar">Something 2</a>
  <a href="link" class="foobar">Something 3</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с помощью библиотеки JQuery:

```
var value = $("#info").html();
$(".info").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).html(value);
});
```